# Liquibase runOnChange="true" but stored function in sqlFile not updated in database for changes

Tags: liquibase

I have a changeset :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">
        <changeSet id="1359722450-38" author="myname" runOnChange="true" >        
           <sqlFile endDelimiter="" splitStatements="false" path="sql/38_getLeadSet.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
           <rollback>DROP FUNCTION `getLeadSet`</rollback>          
        </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

which is included by a mater log files

I if change sth in sql/38_getLeadSet.sql and run liquibase update , I get :

`FUNCTION getLeadSet already exists liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL ... getLeadSet....`

on command line. Seems to be same issue as mentions [here](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-411) ,but I have latest liquibase version

any kind of suggestion is appreciated , thanks

## Edit

Well we need drop sql before the sql file tag e.g

```
 <sql>DROP FUNCTION if exists `getLeadSet`</sql>    
 <sqlFile endDelimiter="" splitStatements="false" path="sql/38_getLeadSet.sql"  relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
 <rollback>DROP FUNCTION `getLeadSet`</rollback>
```

P.S) Liquibase Version: 2.0.5

Answer (score 2):

runOnChange="true" is not working, instead I used ***runAlways="true"*** which is **working**.

I have decided to use runAlways="true" instead of runOnChange="true" in my project, because that doesn't make much difference for my project during the deployment.

liquibase version is 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you rolling back your change before updating it again? Because the function getLeadSet would already be exisiting and you may be getting a sql error rather that a liquiabase one.